# Integrating Veracode logging formatter library into Django project

Tags: python, django, logging, veracode

I'm currently working on resolving a vulnerability issue reported by Veracode, specifically CWE 117 (Improper Output Neutralization for Logs). To address this issue, I need to implement the Veracode logging formatter library available at [logging-formatter-anticrlf](https://github.com/veracode-research/logging-formatter-anticrlf)  in my Django project.

In Django, there is a configuration file called settings.py where the logging behavior for the application is defined using formatters, handlers, and loggers. Here's an example of the configuration:

```
# Logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {filename}:{lineno} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'concurrent_log_handler.ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', '..', 'log-debug.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
            'backupCount': 365 * 7,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'errorfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'errorfile'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'errorfile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'errorfile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'webportal': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'errorfile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

In each module of the Django application, the LOGGER is instantiated as follows:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('webportal')
```

This allows us to start logging based on the Django configuration.

My problem is that I'm unsure where and how to define the anticrlf.LogFormatter() to make it utilized by Django. I need guidance on the proper way to integrate the Veracode logging formatter into my Django project because the provided examples don't show how use it in Django where the settings are different.

Thanks in advance!